# Pipeline project in Jenkins don't trigger a build after check out in SCM(Git Hub)

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control, jenkins-pipeline

1. I got a situation when creating a new Pipeline project:

[image]

2. I ticked the: GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling:
   [image: image1]
   [image: image2]

With FreeStyle, GitHub Organization project everything is working fine, I can trigger a build WHEN pushing to GitHub, but with Pipeline not.

Maybe I missed something?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Check in Github, if the web hook is really set up. IIRC this isn't working for pipelines currently and you have to set it up on your own.

Comment: web Hook is set.. thanks

Comment: Manually or was it there already? Providing some more details might help other having the same issue.

Comment: Manually, as I told in my add.. with FreeStyle project I can trigger a build fine, if push  to github.. With Pipeline project I have to press manually (in Jenkins GUI) to start a build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable Lightweight checkout. From the help button next to it:

> If selected, try to obtain the Pipeline script contents directly from
>   the SCM without performing a full checkout. The advantage of this mode
>   is its efficiency; however, you will not get any changelogs or polling
>   based on the SCM. (If you use checkout scm during the build, this will
>   populate the changelog and initialize polling.) Also build parameters
>   will not be substituted into SCM configuration in this mode. Only
>   selected SCM plugins support this mode.

You might need to run the pipeline one more time after disabling it and then it should start picking up the hooks.

Comment: Nice one. Could you please accept the answer. @Enki